# On refresh Component is removed from DOM and redirecting to home always

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Hey I am using angular 5 in my application. There is one weird situation i am having. When i am refreshing on any component routing link it's always redirecting to home and the last call in the component is ngondestroy before routing to home page.

This is how routing has been defined.

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
{path: 'home', component: HomeComponent,
   children: [
     { path: 'reviews/:reviewTab', component: ReviewsComponent },
     { path: 'activityTimeline', component: ActivityComponent }]},
{path: 'reviewDetails', component: ViewreviewComponent,
   children: [
     { path: 'Comments', component: ReviewCommentDetailComponent },
     { path: 'close', component: CloseReviewComponent}]}
```

html

```
<td *ngIf="review.reviewMaterial.toLowerCase()=='code';else tempContent" [routerLink]="['/reviewDetails/Comments']" [queryParams]="{'bugId' : review.bugId }">
</td>
```

If i am refreshing on http://localhost:4200/#/reviewDetails/Comments?bugId=DRRaa49358
after fetching every information of this component angular is calling onDestroy() cycle and redirecting the page to home page, But i am looking for same screen only.

Please help.

Comment: Can you show your `html` on which you are clicking on to `navigate` to another `component` ?

Comment: <td *ngIf="review.reviewMaterial.toLowerCase()=='code';else tempContent" [routerLink]="['/reviewDetails/Comments']" [queryParams]="{'bugId' : review.bugId }">
This is how Comments component is called from home screen. Or you are asking for Comments component html.

Comment: please include this code in your question post with proper formatting

Comment: Can you please explain me why this is happening.

Comment: can you help with `ReviewCommentDetailComponent` and `ViewreviewComponent ` stripped code